# Can the privilege of down voting be reduced from 125 to 10?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It kind of unfair to HAVE to require 125 rep to vote down.

Can this be 10 to vote up and vote down?

Comment: Could you explain what post needs a down vote or why the site is being harmed by this privilege that is earned with reputation at +125 ?

Comment: ***Why*** is it "kind of unfair"?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't call it unfair, it's just one of the rules valid on all StackExchange sites. One of the reasons that users are required to have at least some reputation before voting is to actually increase the quality of the votes (and to prevent spammers from creating a bunch of accounts and voting each other up).

If you look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation, getting to 15 reputation isn't all that hard (either post a good answer to one of the questions or invest some time to improve 8 posts by editing them).

---

For much more information on the topic, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188611/how-does-a-new-user-begin-using-stack-overflow-stack-exchange) on meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Inofearu since voting down costs rep on answers, this protects your reputation till you have enough to spend on them.

Comment: Oh thank you now I get my it why costs 125 rep now